# Updating /etc/sudoers file in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, sudo

I am trying to update my sudoers file to preserve the http_proxy environment variable but it keeps getting corrupted The  bash script is as follows

`printf 'Defaults    env_keep += "http_proxy https_proxy"' | sudo tee -a /etc/sudoers`

If I edit it manually, it works though

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: when you do it manually, how to you test it is working?

Comment: Try this: `printf "%s\n" 'Defaults env_keep += "http_proxy https_proxy"' | sudo tee -a /etc/sudoers`

Comment: How does the file get corrupted? (What does it look like?)

Answer (score 1):

It may happen if there's no newline at the end of your `/etc/sudoers` file.
It is better to use `echo` command instead of `printf`. Or you can try to add `\n` at the end of string `...proxy"\n'`.